# Stopping execution with error 500

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a small script that resizes some of my featured images in my WC shop, and it kinda works - but I have a small problem.

When I try to make it do multiple products (20+) it chokes and throws an error 500.

Code should speak for itself, but basically it just takes all current products and checks height vs width and if it's different it adjusts the lowest to the highest.

```
 $aWCProductARGS = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            $aWCProducts = new WP_Query( $aWCProductARGS );
            $response['count'] = count($aWCProducts->posts);
            foreach($aWCProducts->posts as $key => $oProduct)
                {
                    $sProductImage = wp_get_attachment_image_src(          get_post_thumbnail_id($oProduct->ID), 'full'  );
                    $sProductImageDIR = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] .    substr($sProductImage[0], strpos($sProductImage[0], "uploads")+7);
                    $sProductImageWidth = $sProductImage[1];
                    $sProductImageHeight = $sProductImage[2];
                    if($sProductImageWidth > $sProductImageHeight)
                    {
                        $thumb_h = $sProductImageWidth;
                        $thumb_w = $sProductImageWidth;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $thumb_h = $sProductImageHeight;
                        $thumb_w = $sProductImageHeight;
                    }
                    $original_info = getimagesize($sProductImageDIR);
                    $original_w         = $original_info[0];
                    $original_h         = $original_info[1];                                        
                    $response['imageCreate'] = imagecreatefromfile($sProductImageDIR);
                    $original_img = imagecreatefromfile($sProductImageDIR);


                    $hal_big_x = $thumb_w / 2;
                    $hal_big_y = $thumb_h / 2;

                    $half_small_x = $original_w / 2; 
                    $half_small_y = $original_h / 2;

                    $coord_x = $hal_big_x - $half_small_x ;
                    $coord_y = $hal_big_y - $half_small_y ;

                    $thumb_img = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w, $thumb_h);
                    if( check_if_png($sProductImageDIR) == 'png' )
                    {
                        imagesavealpha($thumb_img, true);
                        $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumb_img, 0, 0, 0, 127);
                        imagefill($thumb_img, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

                        imagealphablending($original_img, true);
                        imagesavealpha($original_img, TRUE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $white = imagecolorallocate($thumb_img, 255, 255, 255);
                        imagefill($thumb_img, 0, 0, $white);
                    }                                           

                    imagecopyresampled($thumb_img, $original_img,
                                        $coord_x, $coord_y,
                                        0, 0, 
                                        $original_w, $original_h,
                                        $original_w, $original_h);

                    saveimagedata($thumb_img, $sProductImageDIR, $sProductImageDIR);

                    imagedestroy($thumb_img);
                    imagedestroy($original_img);

                    $res = get_attached_file( $oProduct->ID );
                    $metadata = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $oProduct->ID, $sProductImageDIR );
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $post_id, $metadata );   
}
```

I believe it throws the error around a quantity of 20 (when calling `imagecreatefromfile()`).

PHP execution time is set to 500 - but it crashes after around 3-4 sec so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: check your apache error log, or if you are in the development stage , print the error using `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`